# Changing a SOAP WSDL endpoint in Java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have a WSDL that defines a SOAP endpoint. Unfortunately the URL it defines is incorrect. This means when I try to call the service through Java, it is trying to hit an end point that does not exist.

Is there a way I can call a different endpoint through Java? The WSDL contract cannot be changed unfortunately. The Url I want to hit is https://mycorp.com/FBPMSMS.wsdl

Here is a snippet of my code, it was generated through CXF and wsdl2java

```
@WebServiceClient(name = "FBPMSMSService", 
                  wsdlLocation = "http://mycorp.com/FBPMSMS.wsdl",
                  targetNamespace = "http://mycorp.com") 
public class FBPMSMSService extends Service {

    public final static URL WSDL_LOCATION;

    public final static QName SERVICE = new QName("http://mycorp.com", "FBPMSMSService");
    public final static QName FBPMSMSPort = new QName("http://mycorp.com", "FBPMSMSPort");
    static {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://mycorp.com/FBPMSMS.wsdl");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FBPMSMSService.class.getName())
                .log(java.util.logging.Level.INFO, 
                     "Can not initialize the default wsdl from {0}", "http://mycorp.com/FBPMSMS.wsdl");
        }
        WSDL_LOCATION = url;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be very straight forward in the end. I was able to use the below code to modify the endpoint address property on the WSDL

```
FBPMSMSService ss = new FBPMSMSService(wsdlURL, SERVICE_NAME);
FBPMSMSPortType port = ss.getFBPMSMSPort();  

((BindingProvider)port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, "https://mycorp.com/FBPMSMS");
```